# Travis CI deploy build file not in git repo

Tags: bash, electron, travis-ci, electron-builder

Hi I need a bit of help with setting up my travis ci deployment.

I think the source of the issue is that in the github repo I do not have the build file I want to deploy. As in `.gitignore` file I have `build/` folder where my build is generated.

`.travis.yml` file

---

```
osx_image: xcode8.3
sudo: required
dist: trusty
language: c
matrix:
  include:
  - os: osx
  - os: linux
    env: CC=clang CXX=clang++ npm_config_clang=1
    compiler: clang
cache:
  directories:
  - node_modules
  - "$HOME/.electron"
  - "$HOME/.cache"
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - libgnome-keyring-dev
    - icnsutils
before_install:
- mkdir -p /tmp/git-lfs && curl -L https://github.com/github/git-lfs/releases/download/v1.2.1/git-lfs-$([
  "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ] && echo "linux" || echo "darwin")-amd64-1.2.1.tar.gz
  | tar -xz -C /tmp/git-lfs --strip-components 1 && /tmp/git-lfs/git-lfs pull
- if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends
  -y icnsutils graphicsmagick xz-utils; fi
install:
- nvm install 7
- curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
- source ~/.bashrc
- npm install -g xvfb-maybe
- yarn
script:
- yarn run build
branches:
  only:
  - master
deploy:
  provider: s3
  access_key_id: MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  secret_access_key:
    secure: MY_SECURE_ACCESS_SECRET
  bucket: MY_AWS_BUCKET
  local-dir: build/*
  acl: bucket_owner_full_control
  on:
    repo: MY_GITHUB_REPO
env:
  matrix:
    secure: MY_GITHUB_TOKEN
```

---

I know I should have some code in the travis file under `before_install`, but just as I am not familiar with bash, I do not know how to properly reference only the `.dmg` file from my `build` folder. (`build/*.dmg`)

As I said, build folder is excluded from the git repo.

Travis-CI error log is:

```
HEAD detached at ca6dfb3
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    yarn.lock
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (8ab81738da8330c59a8d91b0b3cef454b607dd3d)
/Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.8.40/lib/dpl/provider/s3.rb:47:in `chdir': No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - build/*.dmg (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.8.40/lib/dpl/provider/s3.rb:47:in `push_app'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.8.40/lib/dpl/provider.rb:154:in `block in deploy'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.8.40/lib/dpl/cli.rb:41:in `fold'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.8.40/lib/dpl/provider.rb:154:in `deploy'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.8.40/lib/dpl/provider/s3.rb:75:in `deploy'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.8.40/lib/dpl/cli.rb:32:in `run'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.8.40/lib/dpl/cli.rb:7:in `run'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.8.40/bin/dpl:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/dpl:23:in `load'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/dpl:23:in `<main>'
failed to deploy
/Users/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 878: shell_session_update: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/s3.

> The previous example is almost certainly not ideal, as you probably want to upload your built binaries and documentation. Set `skip_cleanup` to `true` to prevent Travis CI from deleting your build artifacts.

Comment: this worked! However after pointing to specific file extension build/*.dmg it breaks still. Any idea of that?

Comment: `local_dir` clearly takes a directory name, not a glob pattern. In `before_deploy`, either: a) you'd want to create a directory to which you move `build/*.dmg` files (and adjust the `local_dir` value accordingly); or b) delete every file in `build` that does not match the pattern.